# access preboot menu sun x4170

Tags: password-reset, sun

I bought a second hand sun x4170 and need to reset the ilom password. I get output to serial console, but can't access the preboot menu as described by oracle. (by pressing the locate button) Can anyone please give me a detailed instruction starting at null to access the preboot menu on this machine? When do i have to press the locate button. Any help from anybody who has some experience with a sun x4170 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a manual for that box?

Answer (score 0):

Had some problems with it to these days. My problem was, you had to push the locate button directly when you restore the power at the maschine. like in this second. Then on the console you see a message like hold two seconds the locate button to access preboot menue. Otherwise you were to slow. You have to push the button before the boot strap message appears i guess.

Hope it helps

mfg Yogi